# Facebook: list all friends with profile picture, on click redirect to different link

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook to view all friends who use this particular application.Now in my application i can view the profile pictures of friends who are using the same application but on clinking the profile photo application is redirected to their Facebook pages respectively.
On clicking I want to redirect to different link other than Facebook pages. Is it possible ? How ?

My code is

```
<script>
FB.init({
    appId  : '********', //App ID
    channelUrl : 'http://www.***.in/', // Channel File
    status : true, 
    cookie : true,
    xfbml  : true 
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {

        globaluserid=response.session["uid"];
        //fetching friends uids from 'friend' table. We are using FB.api syntax
        FB.api(
                {
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2='+globaluserid
                },
                function(response) {
                //once we get the response of above select query we are going to parse them
                for(i=0;i<response.length;i++)
                {
                //fetching name and square profile photo of each friends
                    FB.api(
                    {
                        method: 'fql.query',
                        query: 'SELECT name,pic_square,username FROM user WHERE uid='+response[i].uid1
                    },
                    function(response) {
                        //creating img tag with src from response and title as friend's name
                        htmlcontent='<img src='+response[0].pic_square+' title='+response[0].name+' alt='+response[0].username+' />';


                    }
                    );
                }
            }
        );
        } else {
            // no user session available, someone you dont know
            top.location.href="../kfb_login.php";
        }
    });
</script>
<div class="just_trying">
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1">    </div> </div>
```

Comment: Is that your full code sample? It doesn't appear it is as there is nothing inserting the `htmlcontent` into the body of your HTML

Comment: it is a working code.Facebook will automatically render the list of friends in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

In the code sample you provided, your FB.api isn't actually doing anything with the information it has retrieved. You are assigning it to an `htmlcontent` variable, but then you aren't using this variable to inject the content into the body of the HTML anywhere. The list of friends photos that you do see are coming from the Login Button tag, `data-show-faces="true"` means that the Login button will show a [Facepile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/) generated exclusively by Facebook code.

So, you want to set `data-show-faces` to be false and modify your Javascript code to this:

```
function(response) {
  //creating img tag with src from response and title as friend's name
  htmlcontent = document.createElement('img');
  htmlcontent.src = response[0].pic_square;
  htmlcontent.title = response[0].name;
  htmlcontent.alt = response[0].username;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(htmlcontent);
}
```

For simplicity, if you're using jQuery, then you'd modify it to:

```
function(response) {
  //creating img tag with src from response and title as friend's name
  htmlcontent = '<img src='+response[0].pic_square+' title='+response[0].name+' alt='+response[0].username+' />'
  $('body').append(htmlcontent);
}
```

Comment: Then there is an error somewhere in your API calls, but the point remains: you need to modify your code to actually insert the results of the API calls into the HTML, the bunch of images that you are already seeing come from the Login Button, and that is why they are linking to the profiles of the people in the image.